# Micro processor logic gates

Tags: processor, digital-logic

Where to get a logic level diagram for a processor , preferably intel 4004.

i have block diagrams but want it to know more at logic level then transistor level.

Answer (score 6):

The schematics of Intel 4004 may be available here:

http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/General/4004_schematic.pdf

Individual components schematics here:

[The 4001 ROM](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~mcnerney/2009-4004/i4001-schematic.gif)
[The 4002 RAM](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~mcnerney/2009-4004/i4002-schematic.gif)
[The 4003 Shift-Register](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~mcnerney/2009-4004/i4003-schematic.gif)
[The 4004 CPU](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~mcnerney/2009-4004/i4004-schematic.gif)
**Source:**
http://www.4004.com/mcs4-masks-schematics-sim.html

**History:**

The chip layout was drawn by hand at a magnification of around 500 times the original size. It was drawn over sheet made of Mylar Quadrille material for its dimensional stability.

Ref.:  *IEEE Solid-State Circuits Magazine ( Volume: 1, Issue: 1, Winter 2009 )*

Comment: Cool.  Let's buy some discrete MOSFETs and a huge PCB. :)

Comment: @OskarSkog: There have been a few such projects already. E.g. https://www.elektormagazine.com/news/record-10-meter-wide-16-bit-megacomputer-from-discrete-parts. "Huge PCB" would be an understatement ;)

Comment: @MSalters 16-bit is quite a different beast than a smaller CPU. 4004 is still entirely reasonable for hand-crafting - I even made a simple 8-bittish CPU myself (though using simple TTLs rather than just transistors - discrete transistors are a bit too slow and unwieldy), and it "only" took about the space of a big tower. Needless to say, pushing it above ~2 MHz is rather impractical, but it was still powerful enough to host a web server (as long as it didn't get more than about five concurrent requests :D).

Comment: Thanks, for transistor level drawing. If we can get Logic level diagram, then it will be more helpful.

Comment: There's no logic level diagram of the 4004. It's a bit tedious but not difficult to figure out the gates from the transistor schematic, though.    @OskarSkog: See the 6502 from discrete transistors: http://monster6502.com/